# Calculating probability from parameter estimates from a regression equation

Tags: java, statistics

**A programming + Statistics Question:**

**Context:**
I am currently building a model simulation (an agent-based model) where each agent (read: person) as a series of variables (i.e. gender, race, martial status, income bracket, education, etc).

This is not a homework question, it's a problem I am trying to solve for work so I do not have to hard code everything, and will make implementing changes to my model much easier and faster.

The variables essentially break down as follows:

```
gender: 0 = female, 1 = male
race:   1 = white, 2 = black, 3 = hispanic, 4 = other
marital status: 1 = married, 2 = divorced, 3 = no married
income: 1 = <20k, 2 = 20k-75k, 3= 75+k
education:  1 = <HS, 2 = HS, 3 = >HS
```

In my dataset I want to predict, for example, smoking status (0 = non-smoker, 1 = smoker).
Easy, do a logistic regression.  Programming in the main effects would not be too difficult since the population model would be as follows:

```
SmokingStatus = b_0 + b_1(gender1) + b_2(race2) + b_3(race3) + b_4(race4) + ... + e
```

**Problem 1:**
As you can see from the equation above, categorical variables create k-1 dummy variables.  Essentially the stats program will create the following dummy variables (using race as an example): race2, race3, race4.  and each will have a beta estimate (that is the ln(OR) relative to the reference group, race1).

**Question 1:**
How would I write my java program to calculate the probability of smoking status from the regression output (the tables I have are SAS ouputs), without creating the corresponding dummy variables in my agent class.

**Problem 2:**
This problem gets even worse when I have interaction terms in my model, since the parameter estimates are the combinations of each variable's dummy-variable.  For example, in above population model + an interaction term between gender and race would be:

```
SmokingStatus = b_0 + b_1(gender1) + b_2(race2) + b_3(race3) + b_4(race4) + B_5(gender1race2) + B_6(gender1race3) + B_7(gender1race4) ... + e
```

**Question 2:**
Given this added complexity, what would be the best approach?

My ultimate goal:
I am trying to write a java program that will take in a (csv) file of variables and their parameter estimates, and essentially 'plug in the values' to generate a probability for my response variable (e.g. smoking status).

Yes I know after I plug in all the values I will have to transform my answer via:

```
Math.exp(logitP)/(1 + Math.exp(logitP))
```

My current (and terrible) solution involves initializing all the dummy variables to 0, then doing a series of if statements to assign a value of 1, then multiplying all the dummies by the corresponding beta estimate (many of the terms will equate to 0)

for example:

```
    int race2 = 0;
    int race3 = 0;
    int race4 = 0;
    int sex0 = 0;

    // race
    if (alcoholAgent.getRace() == 2) {race2 = 1;}
    else if (alcoholAgent.getRace() == 3) {race3 = 1;}
    else if (alcoholAgent.getRace() == 4) {race4 = 1;}

    // sex female is reference group == 0
    if (alcoholAgent.getGender() == 1) {sex0 = 1;}

    // age2-6_race2-4
    if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 2) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==2)) {age2race2 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 2) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==3)) {age2race3 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 2) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==4)) {age2race4 = 1;}

    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 3) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==2)) {age3race2 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 3) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==3)) {age3race3 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 3) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==4)) {age3race4 = 1;}

    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 4) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==2)) {age4race2 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 4) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==3)) {age4race3 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 4) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==4)) {age4race4 = 1;}

    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 5) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==2)) {age5race2 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 5) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==3)) {age5race3 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 5) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==4)) {age5race4 = 1;}

    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 6) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==2)) {age6race2 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 6) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==3)) {age6race3 = 1;}
    else if ((alcoholAgent.getAgeCat() == 6) && (alcoholAgent.getRace()==4)) {age6race4 = 1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any model which makes use of the numerical values of categorical variables is misleading at best. In what sense is race=2 "greater than" race=1? In no sense, of course. My advice is to dump the logistic regression.

Since there is no real ordering of the categorical variables, the best you can do is a look-up table. Just make a multidimensional table indexed by the categorical variables, and count up examples which fall into each bin in the table to find the proportional of examples in each output category. That proportion is your probability of the output category for that combination of input variables.

A look-up table takes all interactions of variables into account. The disadvantage is that the number of table elements may be very large. You may be able to compute the probability of the output category as a product of probabilities from smaller tables (i.e., with fewer indices per table). This is what is called a "naive Bayes" model; it makes an assumption that input variables (or groups of them) are independent given the output category.

Comment: thanks!  A lookup table/hashtable is exactly what I implemented.  I'm slowly working on the code now, and i'll publish the github link when it's ready to be seen by the outside world.  Also: are you saying that you cannot use nominal categorical variables for the predictors in a logistic regression? I have been taught and seen otherwise in the literature.

Comment: @DanielChen It is certainly incorrect to use plain numerical values of nominal categories variables as predictors in logistic regression. Yes, you can get a result; you won't run into any kind of error, you'll just get a meaningless result. It is better (after thinking about it for a few minutes, I'm not sure if it is correct, but it is certainly better) to recode numerical values using an array of binary variables (i.e. recode 0, 1, 2, 3 into (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)) and use those as the inputs, but that's a mess. You can't do better than a look-up table.

Comment: @DanielChen Logistic regression with recoded inputs is convenient, and at least approximately correct, if you are already using LR for some other purpose; that's probably why it is taught.

Comment: Ah, yes it is incorrect to do that, I misunderstood you.  That is why the problem I stated gets very complicated since you would have be create a bunch of dummy varables

Comment: first try at implementing the solution v0.1.0: https://github.com/chendaniely/java-regression-pcalculator